# How can I change the weight of the font in a <Label> in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to do it this way:

```
<Label FontSize="10" FontAttributes="None" />
<Label FontSize="10" FontAttributes="Bold" />
```

However "Bold" makes the characters too dark and "None" makes them too light.  Is there a way that I can change the font to something in between, using an iOS and Android CustomRenderer or something like that?

Comment: Hey,did you solv ethe issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you should take a look at using custom fonts. Otherwise you might need to create custom renderer for both iOS & Android projects and try exposing font properties to the Forms layer. 
It's quicker to use custom font. 
Take a look at this [step by step instructions](https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/) from XamarinHelp

Answer (score 4):

In your case what I have done is use custom fonts with my apps where I can have different variations of the font.

Let's use as example: **Avenir Next** Font Name. I would have:

> **Avenir+Next+Ultralight**
>
> **Avenir+Next+Regular**
>
> **Avenir+Next+Medium**
>
> **Avenir+Next+Demi**
>
> **Avenir+Next+Bold**
>
> **Avenir+Next+Heavy**

This will give you access to all the different weight of the font.

You will need to implement the custom fonts though.

I found [this tutorial](https://xamarinhelp.com/custom-fonts-xamarin-forms/) which does a really good job explaining how to do it.

Once implemented you will be able to assign the weight you prefer to your controls.

Hope this help.-